# what is "log-average"?

Tags: logarithms

It was mentioned in [pLSA](http://www.cs.brown.edu/people/th/papers/Hofmann-UAI99.pdf) paper that **perplexity** refers to the log-averaged inverse probability on unseen data.
Can any one give me the exact formula for calculating **perplexity**

Comment: [Searching Google for "log-average"](http://www.google.com/search?q=log-average) yields as the first hit the Wikipedia article for [geometric mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean), with a conveniently highlighted excerpt stating that it is also sometimes called the log-average...

Comment: @Rahul: I too found the wikipedia article, but im not convinced with that definition in the context of pLSA probabilities. Looking for better information on the same.

Comment: Also at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10302/what-is-perplexity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have looked at the [Wikipedia article on perplexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perplexity). It gives the perplexity of a discrete distribution as

$$2^{-\sum_x p(x)\log_2 p(x)}$$

which could also be written as

$$\exp\left({\sum_x p(x)\log_e \frac{1}{p(x)}}\right)$$

i.e. as a weighted geometric average of the inverses of the probabilities. For a continuous distribution, the sum would turn into a integral.

The article also gives a way of estimating perplexity for a model using $N$ pieces of test data

$$2^{-\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{N} \log_2 q(x_i)}$$

which could also be written

$$\exp\left(\frac{{\sum_{i=1}^N \log_e \left(\dfrac{1}{q(x_i)}\right)}}{N}\right) \text{ or } \sqrt[N]{\prod_{i=1}^N  \frac{1}{q(x_i)}}$$

or in a variety of other ways, and this should make it even clearer where "log-average inverse probability" comes from.

Comment: can the discrete form of perplexity shown here be used to measure the extent of a distribution? or is that reserved for the integral version of perplexity (exponential differential entropy)?

Comment: @develarist That rather depends what you mean by "extent".  Perhaps it might be described as a measurement of something like "diversity"